# How to know if the data on the bus is a data or an instruction for an ARM Cortex-M0?

Tags: architecture, arm, cortex-m

I'm trying to implement a caching algorithm. But I want to cache only the Instructions, and not the data fetched from the memory(obviously). So how do I know that the data on the bus is a Data data or an Instruction data? I tried looking at the HPROT and HTRANS signals, but couldn't get any clarity

Comment: Your answer is in the amba 3 ahb-lite manual at infocenter.arm.com hprot[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out
HPROT[0] tells u if its a data or an opcode fetch

Comment: actually reading deeper into the arm docs it does not always distinguish data from fetch, there are corner cases where it does not.